# how to show large dataset on UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have an array of posts in which the size could be 100000 or more.
I want to show this in an alphabetical order (in which user can navigate to the alphabet easily), what is the best way to do this? Doing a TableView with 100000 entries I think won't be a good idea.. Looking for some suggestions to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a good way to present 100,000 records on an iPhone or iPad.  I guess the question I would ask is does the user REALLY need to access that volume of data at one time on those types of devices?

If not, then I think you could resolve this with either some filters (to limit the results in a paginated grid) or a decent search algorithm.

Cheers!

Comment: I was thinking of paging the UITableView.. just like the app store.. wonder how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using table view.For users comfort you can add list of alpha bate on the table view as  buttons and depending on user selection related search results can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would present this data in a TableView, but I would try and make the user filter the 100,000 posts somehow so that at no stage you've actually got 100,000 posts loaded in the TableView.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is you first think on trimming your array of posts a little bit, probably until you have no more than a few hundred. That way your sort process will be faster and then you can load them already sorted in a view. That way the user will actually spend time looking at the list.

Honestly, even if you load those hundred thousand or more In a sorted view, there are only 26 letters in the alphabet, and it would show around 3800 posts per letter, assuming your posts are evenly distributed, which again your users will not spend the time looking at.